# auto add route parameter to url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have 2 urls on one page: `http://host/home/list`  and `http://host/home/list/1`. if i click on second url then first url renders with param 1, so url1 equals ulr2 (url1 = `http://host/home/list/1` and url2=`http://host/home/list/1`)

i use such code

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink("link", "DesignerFiles", "Home", null, null)%> url1

<%= Html.ActionLink("link", "DesignerFiles", "Home", new { id = 1} , null)%> url2
```

what the problem?

Comment: Well, the two URLs are two different routes, for one thing.  Consider using `RouteLink` instead.  RouteLink will force you to specify the route used for each link, and should clean up the variation you see between the two links.

Comment: emmm...., more clear please or show example :)

Comment: can you provide routing configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a simliar issue with sub level and tertiary navigation elements.  IE - a link that should go to /Home/About from the /Home/About/People would append /People to the first link.  I used the following method to get this to work correctly:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Link", "About", "Home", new with {.section = nothing}, nothing%>
<%=Html.ActionLink("Link2", "About", "Home", new with {.section = "People"}, nothing%>
```

That seemed to force the ActionLink to not include the additional parameter that was in the current context of my view.  Side note, I changed the dafault {controller}/{action}/{id} to {controller}/{action}/{section} - which is why you see section in my route values.